# Firebase Functions: Unable to access firebase-admin when serving locally

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I've got a Firebase cloud function that use Expressjs to make some REST endpoints. The functions get or set data to `Firestore` using `firebase-admin`. When I deploy my functions live they work fine. However when I try to run them locally using `firebase serve` they crash when trying to access `firestore`. The function works correctly when it is deployed, I only have this issue when serving it locally.

Here is a super stripped down function that shows where the crash happens:

```
  app.get('/account/:uId/persona/:pId/test', (req, res) => {
    const uid = req.params.uId;
    const pid = req.params.pId;

    admin.firestore()
      .collection('my-collection')
      .doc(uid)
      .get()
      .then((succ) => res.status(204).send("success"))
      .catch(err => res.status(500).send("failure"))
  });
```

Its not hitting the `catch` at then end of my function. The terminal log says:

```
info: User function triggered, starting execution
info: Execution took 1404 ms, finished with status: 'crash'
```

And the response says:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "status": "INTERNAL",
        "message": "function crashed",
        "errors": [
            "socket hang up"
        ]
    }
}
```

I setup admin credential, but it didn't make a difference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_admin_credentials_optional

Any ideas whats going on?